# ¿Cómo exporto una tabla a un doc. excel desde un procedimiento almacenado en C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

Tengo mi procedimiento que trae una tabla y lo que quiero es que me lo exporte a `Excel` al presionar un botón.

```
QUERY: CREATE PROC planilla.USP_T_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL_HISTORICO_X_TRABAJADOR_LISTAR

@RucE char(11),
@Ejer char(4),
@Prdo char(2),
@Sem char(2),
@IC_TipoPlan char(1),
@Usu nvarchar(20),
@Cd_ModContrato nvarchar(1000)
as
declare
@ConsultaDiasConceptuales varchar(max) = '',
@TipoDiasConceptuales varchar(max) = '',
@SumaDiasConceptuales varchar(max) = '',
@CaseDiasConceptuales varchar(max) = '',
@SelectDiasConceptuales varchar(max) = '',
@GroupByDiasConceptuales varchar(max) = ''

set @Sem= isnull(@Sem,'')

if (@IC_TipoPlan = 'E' and exists (select top 1 * from planilla.T_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL where C_RUC_EMPRESA=@RucE))
Begin
    select @TipoDiasConceptuales += '''' + C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL + ''' as [' + C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL + '|' + C_NOMBRE_CORTO + '],',
            @CaseDiasConceptuales += 'case when ([' + C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL + '|' + C_NOMBRE_CORTO + ']) = T1.C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL then T1.C_CANTIDAD_DIAS else 0.00 end as [' + C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL + '|' + C_NOMBRE_CORTO + '],',
            @SumaDiasConceptuales += 'SUM([' + C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL + '|' + C_NOMBRE_CORTO + ']) as [' + C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL + '|' + C_NOMBRE_CORTO + '],',
            @SelectDiasConceptuales += ',ISNULL([' + C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL + '|' + C_NOMBRE_CORTO + '],0.00) as [' + C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL + '|' + C_NOMBRE_CORTO + ']',
            @GroupByDiasConceptuales += 'diascpt.[' + C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL + '|' + C_NOMBRE_CORTO + '],'
    from planilla.T_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL
    where C_RUC_EMPRESA=@RucE
    print @SelectDiasConceptuales
    if (LEN(@TipoDiasConceptuales) > 0) set @TipoDiasConceptuales = SUBSTRING(@TipoDiasConceptuales, 1, LEN(@TipoDiasConceptuales) - 1)
    if (LEN(@SumaDiasConceptuales) > 0) set @SumaDiasConceptuales = SUBSTRING(@SumaDiasConceptuales, 1, LEN(@SumaDiasConceptuales) - 1)
    if (LEN(@CaseDiasConceptuales) > 0) set @CaseDiasConceptuales = SUBSTRING(@CaseDiasConceptuales, 1, LEN(@CaseDiasConceptuales) - 1)
    --if (LEN(@SelectDiasConceptuales) > 0) set @SelectDiasConceptuales = SUBSTRING(@SelectDiasConceptuales, 1, LEN(@SelectDiasConceptuales) - 1)
    --if (LEN(@GroupByDiasConceptuales) > 0) set @GroupByDiasConceptuales = SUBSTRING(@GroupByDiasConceptuales, 1, LEN(@GroupByDiasConceptuales) - 1)

    --set @ConsultaDiasConceptuales =

End

exec('select tra.Cd_Trab'+@SelectDiasConceptuales+'
 from Trabajador tra 
    left join
    ( 
        select T2.C_CODIGO_TRABAJADOR,' + @SumaDiasConceptuales + '
        from
        (
            select T1.C_CODIGO_TRABAJADOR,' + @CaseDiasConceptuales + '
            from
            (
                select C_CODIGO_TRABAJADOR,' + @TipoDiasConceptuales + ',C_CODIGO_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL,C_CANTIDAD_DIAS
                from planilla.T_DIA_CONCEPTUAL_HISTORICO_X_TRABAJADOR
                where C_RUC_EMPRESA=''' + @RucE + ''' and C_EJERCICIO=''' + @Ejer + ''' and C_PERIODO=''' + @Prdo + '''
            ) as T1
        ) as T2
        group by T2.C_CODIGO_TRABAJADOR

    ) as diascpt on tra.Cd_Trab = diascpt.C_CODIGO_TRABAJADOR 
 where tra.RucE = '''+@RucE+''' and tra.IC_TipoPlan='''+@IC_TipoPlan+''' and tra.Cd_Trab in (select Cd_Trab from dbo.fn_SelectTrab2('''+@RucE+''','''+@Ejer+''','''+@Prdo+''','''+@Sem+''','''+@IC_TipoPlan+''','''+@Cd_ModContrato+''',''1'','''+@Usu+'''))')
```

aquí está mi DAO

```
    public ClassResultPV Pln_CargarDiasConceptuales(DtoB dto)
    {
        ClassResultPV cr = new ClassResultPV();
        DtoTareo dtoTareo = (DtoTareo)dto;
        SqlParameter[] pr = new SqlParameter[7];
        try
        {
            pr[0] = new SqlParameter("@RucE", SqlDbType.Char, 11);
            pr[0].Value = dtoTareo.RucE;

            pr[1] = new SqlParameter("@Ejer", SqlDbType.Char, 4);
            pr[1].Value = dtoTareo.Ejer;

            pr[2] = new SqlParameter("@Prdo", SqlDbType.Char, 2);
            pr[2].Value = dtoTareo.Prdo;

            pr[3] = new SqlParameter("@Sem", SqlDbType.Char, 2);
            pr[3].Value = Pv_ValidaPrNull(dtoTareo.Sem);

            pr[4] = new SqlParameter("@IC_TipPlan", SqlDbType.Char, 1);
            pr[4].Value = dtoTareo.TipPlan;

            pr[5] = new SqlParameter("@Usu", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
            pr[5].Value = dtoTareo.Usu;

            pr[6] = new SqlParameter("@Cd_ModContrato", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000);
            pr[6].Value = Pv_ValidaPrNull(dtoTareo.Cd_ModContrato);

            cr.DS = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(objCn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "USP_T_TIPO_DIA_CONCEPTUAL_HISTORICO_X_TRABAJADOR_LISTAR", pr);
            cr.DT = cr.DS.Tables.Count > 0 ? cr.DS.Tables[0] : new DataTable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cr.ErrorMsj = "Error al consultar el tareaje";
            cr.ErrorEx = ex.Message;
            cr.LugarError = ex.StackTrace;
        }
        return cr;
    }
```

este es mi botón pero me llena separado por ","

```
    private void btnImportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Crear un objeto SqlConnection, y luego pasar la ConnectionString al constructor.            
        try
        {
            ClassResultPV cr;
            {
                CtrTareo ctr = new CtrTareo();
                cr = ctr.Pln_CargarDiasConceptuales(new DtoTareo()
                {
                    RucE = Globales.RucEmp,
                    Ejer = Globales.EjeEmp,
                    Prdo = Globales.Prdo,
                    TipPlan = Globales.TipoPlanilla == TipPlanilla.Empleados ? "E" : "O",
                    Sem = Globales.TipoPlanilla == TipPlanilla.Empleados ? null : Globales.Semana,
                    Usu = Globales.UsuActual,
                    Cd_ModContrato = chkModContrato.Visible == true ? HelpPV.ObtenerCodidoStr_CheckedComboBoxEdit(chkModContrato, ',') : null
                });
                dtdc = cr.DT;
            }

            try
            {
                //open file
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\\Import_Dias_Conceptuales.xls");
                // First we will write the headers.
                //DataTable dt = m_dsProducts.Tables[0];
                int iColCount = dtdc.Columns.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(dtdc.Columns[i]);
                    if (i < iColCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(",");
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                // Now write all the rows.

                foreach (DataRow dr in dtdc.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                        {
                            sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                        }
                        if (i < iColCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(",");
                        }
                    }

                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: boton en un formulario c#, adjunte mi DAO lo que quiero es enviar el DT a un doc excel

Comment: en si que deseas hacer?

Comment: hacer un formato de importación exportando la tabla para poder modificarla

Answer (score 0):

Supongo por tu pregunta que lo que necesitas es crear un archivo de Excel con el contenido de un `DataTable`.

Por lo que veo (corrígeme si me equivoco), estás utilizando `StreamWriter` para escribir los datos del `DataTable`. El problema es que Excel tiene un formato especial de almacenamiento de archivos. Lo que estás haciendo realmente es rellenar un archivo de texto con los campos separados por comas.

Los archivos de texto separados por tabuladores, comas o puntos y comas es lo que se conoce como archivos CSV. Excel puede leer este tipo de archivos pero no es el formato nativo de esta aplicación.

Si lo que quieres es escribir un archivo Excel, tendrás que utilizar alguna de las librerías específicas para este formato.

Particularmente yo utilizo [ClosedXml](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml), aunque encontrarás varias librerías similares.